# Paypal IPN Simulator working but Sandbox transactions not working with AWS Lambda - just gives 500 error

Tags: aws-lambda, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, aws-api-gateway

I've been able to make the simulator work with my script. The script is executed and verified and everything. It's all on AWS Lambda.

But, then, I create two sandbox accounts, one for seller and one for buyer and make a transaction using PayPal Standard Button with `notify_url` set to the correct IPN URL.

Now, I make a transaction but I see no logs in AWS CloudWatch or any invocations of the Lambda. The Paypal IPN History just says 500 and that's it. No other explanation or anything. What am I missing..?

Comment: Were AWS CloudWatch logs that you mentioned for API Gateway or for Lambda? If the latter, try enabling CloudWatch logs for API Gateway.

Comment: Okay. That's a good suggestion.